# Can One disambiguate between simple operators and compound assignment operators in ruby?

Tags: ruby, operators

Can Anyone point Me in the direction of how to tell when, for example, the + operator is used in ruby as opposed to the += operator from the inside of the + operator's definition? To illustrate:

```
class A
    def +(b)
        if is_theCallActuallyACompoundAssignment?
            compoundAssignment = true
        else
            compoundAssignment = false
        end
        doOtherStuff
    end
end
```

Is there a Kernel method, perhaps?

Comment: To deprecate the use of += and not +.

Comment: I'm afraid, it's not possible at the moment.

Comment: Well, here's to hoping the ability shows up in Ruby 2.0. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code:

```
a += 5
```

Gets translated to this:

```
a = a + 5
```

Your `+` method will not know that you received a compound assignment.